# Installing Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox without deleting Windows

Tags: partitioning, windows, virtualbox, oracle, virtualization

This may seem like a dumb question, but on this screen:

[image]

of the Ubuntu installation, if I select the first option, "erase disk and install Ubuntu", it should only affect the portion of the disk that I allocated to this VM, correct? I just want to make sure I don't lose all my files.

Answer (score 2):

Thats perfectly fine to choose and will not affect your windows installation in any way, this only sees the allocated file space you have created for the VM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's correct! You only erase and install on the disk you assign to this VM. You don't lose data on other disks.